# Checking a hire bike is properly docked

Tags: london, rental, bicycles

I docked a Boris bike (Santander Cycle (used to be called Barclays Cycle)), part of the London scheme of bikes offered to hire for a short time.

But I'm not sure if I checked for the green light when you dock it. The red rear lights are still flashing, as if it's not docked properly. What do I do? I don't want to be charged extra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1.** Give it a tug.

If your bike hasn't docked properly, you should be able to pull it out again. But don't use excessive force. Even if it doesn't come out, it's no guarantee that it's correctly docked.

**2.** Check your journey history.

Go to the docking station and press the option to print a journey history receipt. You have to insert your bank card so it can identify you, then you will see a list of journeys you made over the last week or so. If your journey is on there, then you're safe (N.B., journeys that last less than 10 mins may not show).